# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null with inJustDecodeBounds set to false

Tags: android, android-bitmap

In my android app I am trying to create a Bitmap file from path.

Here is the path

```
localImagePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Hootout/HootImages/Profilepic/user_profile_photo.jpg"
```

Here is code for creating bitmap.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localImagePath, options);
```

The bitmap file always turns out to be null.

What other things can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a bitmap from file path

```
File imgFile = new  File("/storage/emulated/0/Hootout/HootImages/Profilepic/user_profile_photo.jpg");
if(imgFile.exists()){
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

I think you are giving the wrong file path.
Let me know if any error again.

Comment: I wasn't giving wrong path but an invalid one.  The folder containing the picture was getting deleted. Marking as answer.  Thanks.